# Should git questions from Super User be moved to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, superuser

Currently, there are 91 `[git]` [questions on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/~git~) compared to 3,588 at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/~git~). Are there reasons for keeping this split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, from a wider angle I'd say that many computer (power/super) users would actually benefit a lot by facilitating revision control for their every day document handling(/backup) (see Martin Fowlers Bliki page on Subversion for [a particular nifty use case](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Subversion.html), and more thoughts regarding this).

That said, I've yet to witness this technique being applied properly by a not so technical and especially not so programming oriented group of users (e.g. in a corporate environment). In addition Git will likely be the least appealing/usable DVCS for the non technical users out there, IMO (no preference stated here, just my observations for this particular use case).

Since looking at a few sample questions seems to indicate that most are programming related indeed, you have a point here, but be aware that this would be opening a can of worms, as their are [quite](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tortoise-git) [some](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/svn) [other](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tortoise-svn) [version control](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version-control) [related](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mercurial) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tortoise-hg) too ;)